# How to restrict flyway init being called on an existing DB

Tags: ant, flyway

I am using an ant script which will cane be used on an empty and existing DB.
My Ant executes perfectly fine on an empty schema. But when I execute it again, it throws "Schema already initialized" exception.

Please let  me know how I can control the schema initialization in an ant script. Any sample example would be helpful

Regards,
Kavitha

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to init an empty schema.

Init is there to mark an existing database you can't drop (ex: production) as having a certain version. Flyway will then only migrate from there on forward.

Comment: Hi Axel..thanks for the info..I am uisng an existing DB which do not have schema_history created in it. While I try to execute the ant script on this DB, I get the error "Found non-empty schema 'dbo' without metadata table! Use init() first to initialize the metadata table."...How can I fix this issue?

Comment: run init once and then migrate after that